# Flutter: Building a scale and easy maintain folder structure

Tags: android, flutter, dart, design-patterns, flutter-dependencies

I'm doing a refactor for a couple of my flutter apps. at the time I made those apps I didn't care much about the **Folder structure**.

And because of that and after my apps get bigger on each update, the process becomes harder/difficult to maintain.

So I decided to refactor those apps and rebuild them on clean architecture.

ِAnd I have read this [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-scalable-folder-files-structure-8f860faafebd) that explains how to create a scalable folder & files structure with the bloc

But I didn't understand 2 things:

1. what is the difference between *core* and *modules*?
2. he said that core, modules must-have on every feature 4 folders bloc, models, screens ... but in his examples, the auth and settings the core features didn't have that? and what if my auth isn't had a UI but just logic to get the current app auth state?

I'm not so familiar with DDD principles, and I didn't know how to apply them with my apps.

For example one of my apps is a finance app that collects your daily expenses and creates reports and here's currently folder structure.

[image]

Comment: Looking at the article, it seems like the `core` is the directory where you would usually add your logic for core features of your app or handle connection with a local management / external service (for example: Login via `auth`, CRUD operations via `preferences` or `database`, etc). Modules could be the ones handling them or even custom data objects / models for storing data (this is not very clear from the article).

Comment: i don't think your question is on-topic here, probably more relevant at https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, potentially

Answer (score 0):

I recently started to use GetX and my architectural opinions changed.
GetX called its state managers - `controllers`.

Therefore, we have an obvious architectural pattern choice - **MVC**.

Yes `GetControllers` are not exactly **Controller** in MVC, but who cares?

Ergo, next folder structure:

```
controller \
           user_controller.dart
           todo_controller.dart        
model \         
       user.dart
       user_service.dart //firebase connection
       todo.dart
       todo_service.dart 

view \
      user_screen.dart
      todo_screen.dart

      widgets \
               custom_button.dart
```

If we have more than 3 features in our app then

```
controller \
           feature1 \
                    feature1_controller.dart
          ...
           featureN \      
model \
      feature1 \
               feature1.dart
               feature1_service.dart //firebase connection
       ...
      featureN \

view \
     feature1 \
               feature1_screen.dart
     ...
     featureN \ 

     widgets \
             custom_button.dart
```

This approach is called layer-first.

An alternative feature-first approach should never be used.
If the app is too big for the layer-first approach, it should be split into several packages.

All the above is my humble opinion, obviously.

In software development almost everything is trade-off.